# ansible shell Linux

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, ansible

Ok, below I read a line from a file which is an app with parameters. I read it in a need to know how to run in on the Linux server from ansible. I used ansible to read in the line but can't figure out how to run it with shell: or command:. Or is that not the correct way using ansible. If I `-shell: echo "{{ connection.stdout }}"` it echos the line but can't figure out how to run in as if I was on that machine using the command-line.

```
name: extract command from file

slurp:

src: /home/ansible/con.txt

register: connection

shell: content="{{ connection.stdout }}"
```

I can echo connection.stdout and it returns the line I need to run but can't figure out how to run it on the machine. The file is there and I read the file and can echo the line in the file. Just need to be able to run that line on the machine.
Thanks

Comment: for some reason it is not letting me format correctly in the post

Comment: Maybe use ``` <your code> ``` where ``` is on a newline.

Comment: @TyBoard you have formatting buttons on top of the editor area + help on the right side of the screen while creating/editing your answer. This should help you to format your question correctly (which is really needed to understand your current issue).

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you run following code:

```
- name: Execute the command in remote shell; stdout goes to the specified file on the remote.
  shell: somescript.sh >> somelog.txt
```

Then it will execute somescript.sh and write the output generated by the script into somelog.txt

Through your description I assume you do:

```
- name: Execute the command in remote shell; stdout goes to the specified file on the remote.
  shell: echo "somescript.sh >> somelog.txt"
```

Then **echo** gets executed which prints *somescript.sh >> somelog.txt*

Comment: The con.txt file holds a app with parameters I need to execute on the system. I just can't figure out how to get the command from the file and execute it on the machine.

Comment: Another app finishes and the last things it spits out is the command I need to run on other servers. I piped that to con.txt so I could copy it to other servers and then run it. I just can't figure out how to run it from the file on the servers.

Comment: Thanks, I need to take a break as I figured out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Ahh, I see. If only the command is within con.txt, then ... shell: $(echo con.txt) should work. Then echo will "extract" the command and $() will execute it. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147420/what-is-in-a-command might describe it a little bit better.